# Error AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'json' occures when importing functions from other files

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I'm writting an automated test which uses 3 files `helpers.py` where I store fucntion of registering, `test_mails.py` where the test is executed and it runs checking for registration for 5 mails in list, `login_credentials.py` where json dictionaries are stored. `test_mails.py` uses unittest library and import main `sing_up` function for trying to register 5 emails through api requests. The aim of test is to check if system doesn't let these mails to pass. However, when in `test_mails.py`I try to use methods from libs `json` or`requesrts` with `sing_up` function I get these types of errors. `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'json'`. This also applies to `status_code` method How to solve it?
Here are files:
**helpers.py**

```
import json
import requests


def sign_up(data):
    with requests.Session() as session:
        sign_up = session.post(
            f'https://siteexample/api/register',
            headers={
                'content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            data=json.dumps(data)
        )
        print(sign_up.content)
        print(sign_up.status_code)
```

**test.mails.py**

```
import unittest
import requests
import json
from login_credentials import data, emails_list
from helpers import *


class Mails(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_sign_up_public_emails(self):
        emails_dict_ls = {}
        for email in emails_list:
            data_copy = data.copy()
            data_copy["email"] = email
            emails_dict_ls.update(data_copy)
            sign_up(emails_dict_ls)

            if 'email' in sign_up.json() and "User with this Email already exists." in 
sign_up.json()['email']:
                registering = False
            else:
                registering = True
                assert self.assertEqual(sign_up.status_code, 400)
                assert sign_up.json()['status_code'] == "NOT_CONFIRMED_EMAIL"
            return registering
```

**login_credentials.py**

```
data = {
    "company": "Company",
    "phone": "+1111111",
    "email": "",
    "password1": "defaultpassword",
    "password2": "defaultpassword",
    "terms_agree": True,
    "first_name": "TestUser",
    "last_name": "One"
}

emails_list = ['mailtest.unconfirm@yahoo.com',
               'mailtest.unconfirm@gmail.com',
               'mailtest.unconfirm@ukr.net',
               'mailtest.unconfirm@outlook.com',
               'mailtest.unconfirm@icloud.com'
               ]
```

Comment: You can just do `json=data` instead of `json.dumps(data)`

Comment: The reason it's returning the error is because you aren't returning any values from your `sign_up` function. Please `return sign_up` to return the response object, from which .json() can be called.

Comment: In test.mails.py, `sign_up` is a function. Not the variable of the same that is defined inside that function.

Comment: @matszwecja so I need to change the logic of test to use json and etc?

Comment: No, you need to stop using a function name like it is a variable. What makes you think it has `.json()` attribute?

Comment: @matszwecja okay, understood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `sign_up` function in helpers.py. You'll have to return the response so that `.json()` can be called.

Also, you can use `json=data` instead of `data=json.dumps(data)` since it's already a built-in function of python-requests.

```
def sign_up(data):
  with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.post(
        f'https://siteexample/api/register',
        headers={
            'content-type': 'application/json',
        },
        json=data
    )
    return response
```

In test_mails.py, You're just calling the function and not storing the value in a variable.

```
def test_sign_up_public_emails(self):
    emails_dict_ls = {}
    for email in emails_list:
        data_copy = data.copy()
        data_copy["email"] = email
        emails_dict_ls.update(data_copy)
        sign_resp = sign_up(emails_dict_ls)

        if 'email' in sign_resp.json()
```

Comment: The exact same error, or has it changed to something else?

Comment: Updated page and saw your edited answer, it helped

Comment: Ah, perfect. Game on!